# Firefox OS Dial Web Activity

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I'm developing an app for Firefox OS that interacts with the dial Web Activity.
As Mozilla's guide I'm doing this:

```
var call = new MozActivity({
    name: "dial",
    data: {
        number: "+46777888999"
    }
});
```

And it works, but, I want that it **calls directly without click on green call button**.
I've digged all MDN to get this, but I can't find any other attribute of this Data to get this goal.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with the [WebTelephony API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/Telephony/Introduction_to_WebTelephony) but only for certified applications :

```
// Telephony object
var tel = navigator.mozTelephony;

// Place a call
var call = tel.dial("123456789");
```

So for now, it's impossible  as [certified applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Security/Security_model) are basically system applications (OS, OEM, and operators approved), so using the Web Activities is the way to go right now.

Comment: Yeah I saw about it, but it not work on LG Fireweb.
My question is related to Web Activities at all, to understand if there is more attributes to set such make a directly call.

Comment: No, Web Activities doesn't allow you to call directly as it needs user interaction to make the call (press the green button).